# Module name resolution relative to tsconfig or baseUrl?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

it is possible to import module using absolute paths (resp path relative to tsconfig)?

I tend to move some files (views) to subdirectories and I want to avoid fixing imports from those files.

Currently in my-component.ts:

```
import { MyService } from '../../myservice';
```

file system:

```
src [Folder]
   app [Folder]
      subfolder [Folder]
          my-component [Folder]
             my-component.ts
      myservice.ts
      tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using `webpack` as a bundling tool or just `typescript`?

Comment: WebPack. Actually it is default project created by angular CLI: `ng new my-app`, so it is very easy to reproduce if you follow [Angular QuickStart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by modifying the webpack configuration. In the `webpack.config.js` find the line with `"alias":` and replace it with this:

```
"alias": { ... rxPaths(), mySrc: './src' },
```

This will add `src` folder as the root path when resolving modules. Now you can edit to your `main.ts` to check if that works.

You should also take note to make the `baseUrl` configuration in your `tsconfig.json` the same as the `alias` in the webpack config:

```
"baseUrl": "./src"
```

Tested this with `Angular: 5.2.5` and `Node 8.4.0`